# Constant problems with php-fpm, CPU usage 100% non-stop (No visitors even)

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, php7, percona, mysql5.7

We are running two servers one for the application and one for the DB and some other software to keep the load off from the application's server, we are running CentOS and the latest version of PHP (7.3), Nginx (1.17.9), Percona MySQL (5.7), Redis, ElasticSearch.

We already tried everything we know, but nothing worked so far if anyone could point us to the right direction would be great.

**CPU**

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                32
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-31
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    8
Socket(s):             2
NUMA node(s):          2
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 63
Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v3 @ 2.40GHz
Stepping:              2
CPU MHz:               2781.445
CPU max MHz:           3200.0000
CPU min MHz:           1200.0000
BogoMIPS:              4788.97
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              20480K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-7,16-23
NUMA node1 CPU(s):     8-15,24-31
Flags:                 fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm epb invpcid_single intel_ppin ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid cqm xsaveopt cqm_llc cqm_occup_llc dtherm ida arat pln pts md_clear spec_ctrl intel_stibp flush_l1d
```

**Application's Server RAM**

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            23G        9.6G         10G        1.2G        3.3G        8.6G
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```

**MySQL's Server RAM**

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            31G         10G         13G        1.5G        6.6G         18G
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```

**Nginx Main Configuration**

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile 100000;

## Load Dynamic Modules ##
#load_module modules/ngx_pagespeed.so;
load_module modules/ngx_http_geoip_module.so;
#load_module modules/ngx_http_perl_module.so;
#load_module modules/ngx_http_brotli_filter_module.so;
#load_module modules/ngx_http_brotli_static_module.so;

pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {

  worker_connections 10524;
  multi_accept on;
  accept_mutex off;
}

http {

  index index.html index.php;
  include mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  #geoip_country /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat;

  log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" $status $bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" - "$request_id"';
  #log_format  error403  '$remote_addr - [$time_local] "$request" "$http_user_agent" - "$request_id" - "$geoip_country_code"';

  ## Nginx amplify metrics
  log_format main_ext '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" '
  '"$host" sn="$server_name" '
  'rt=$request_time '
  'ua="$upstream_addr" us="$upstream_status" '
  'ut="$upstream_response_time" ul="$upstream_response_length" '
  'cs=$upstream_cache_status' ;

  ## Enable POST logging in admin and mask passwords
  # log_format adminpost '$remote_addr - "$http_x_forwarded_for" $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$masked_post_pwd_data"';
  # perl_set $masked_post_pwd_data '
  #            sub {
  #                    my $r = shift;
  #                    my $req =  $r->request_body;
  ### test either one line below or create different regex
  ##  $req =~ s/password(%5D|_.+?)?\=\w+/PASSWORD_REMOVED/g;
  ##  $req =~ s/password.+/PASSWORD_REMOVED/g;
  #                    return $req;
  #                } ';

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main_ext;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;

  keepalive_timeout 5;
  autoindex off;
  server_tokens off;
  port_in_redirect  off;
  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  aio threads=default;

  #sendfile_max_chunk 512k;
  client_max_body_size 64m;
  client_body_buffer_size 128k;
  client_header_buffer_size 16k;
  large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;

  fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
  fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;

  # Microcache
  #proxy_cache_path /tmp/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=microcache:100M max_size=500M inactive=2h;

  ## Flood protection example (see conf_m2/extra_protect.conf)
  limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=zone1:35m rate=1r/s;
  limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=zone2:35m rate=1r/s;
  limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=zone3:35m rate=1r/s;

  ## Cache open FD
  open_file_cache max=35000 inactive=30s;
  open_file_cache_valid 30s;
  open_file_cache_min_uses 2;

  ##  SSL global settings
  #ssl_session_cache        shared:SSL:45m;
  #ssl_session_timeout  30m;
  #ssl_protocols        TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
  #ssl_ciphers                "ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:!3DES:!aNULL:!MD5";
  #ssl_prefer_server_ciphers    on;
  #ssl_dhparam      /etc/ssl/certs/dhparams.pem;
  #ssl_ecdh_curve       secp384r1;
  #ssl_buffer_size      4k;

  #ssl_stapling on;
  #ssl_trusted_certificate  /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem;
  #resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=3600s;
  #resolver_timeout 5s;
  ## Get real ip from proxy
  #set_real_ip_from 127.0.0.1;
  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

  ## Main domain configuration
  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;

}
```

**Nginx Configuration**

```
## Maps config file
include conf_m2/maps.conf;

## certbot-auto renew webroot
#  server {
#    listen 80;
#    server_name example.com;
#
#    location ~ /\.well-known/acme-challenge {
#        root $MAGE_ROOT/pub;
#    }
#
#    location / { return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;  }
#  }

## Proxy server to terminate ssl before varnish
#server {
#listen 80;
#listen 443 ssl http2;
#server_name domain.com;
## Gzipping is an easy way to reduce page weight
#gzip on;
#gzip_vary on;
#gzip_proxied any;
#gzip_types application/javascript application/x-javascript application/rss+xml text/javascript text/css text/plain image/x-icon image/svg+xml;
#gzip_buffers 4 16k;
#gzip_comp_level 6;
# Brotli compression alternative to Gzip
#brotli              on;
#brotli_types        text/xml image/svg+xml application/x-font-ttf image/vnd.microsoft.icon application/x-font-opentype application/json font/eot application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/javascript font/otf application/xml application/xhtml+xml text/javascript application/x-javascript text/plain application/x-font-truetype application/xml+rss image/x-icon font/opentype text/css image/x-win-bitmap;
#brotli_comp_level   8;
#if ($api_access) {
#  return 403;
#}
#if ($bad_client) {
#  return 403;
#}
## Server maintenance block.
#include conf_m2/maintenance.conf;
## SSL key and cert location
#ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
#ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
#include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
#ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
## Proxy-pass to Varnish
#location / {
#  include /etc/nginx/conf_m2/varnish_proxy.conf;
#}
#}

server {

  listen 80 reuseport;
  server_name domain.com;
  location / {

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }
}

server {

  #listen 80 reuseport;
  listen 443 reuseport ssl http2;
  server_name domain.com;

  ## Set Magento root folder
  set $MAGE_ROOT /home/domain.com/m2/public;
  ## Set main public directory /pub
  root $MAGE_ROOT/pub;

  ## Gzipping is an easy way to reduce page weight
  gzip on;
  gzip_vary on;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_types application/javascript application/x-javascript application/rss+xml text/javascript text/css text/plain image/x-icon image/svg+xml;
  gzip_buffers 4 16k;
  gzip_comp_level 6;

  # Brotli compression alternative to Gzip
  #brotli              on;
  #brotli_types        text/xml image/svg+xml application/x-font-ttf image/vnd.microsoft.icon application/x-font-opentype application/json font/eot application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/javascript font/otf application/xml application/xhtml+xml text/javascript application/x-javascript text/plain application/x-font-truetype application/xml+rss image/x-icon font/opentype text/css image/x-win-bitmap;
  #brotli_comp_level   8;

  if ($api_access) {

    return 403;
  }
  if ($bad_client) {

    return 403;
  }

  ## Server maintenance block.
  include conf_m2/maintenance.conf;



  ## SSL key and cert location
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

  # Improve HTTPS performance
  http2_max_field_size 16k;
  http2_max_header_size 32k;
  ssl_buffer_size 1369;
  ssl_session_tickets on;

  location ^~ /ms-tool/ {

    root $MAGE_ROOT;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;

    location ~ \.php$ {

      try_files $uri =404;
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      include fastcgi_params;
    }
  }

  location ~ bridge_gWtFceci.php$ {

    root $MAGE_ROOT;
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }

  ## phpMyAdmin configuration
  include conf_m2/phpmyadmin.conf;

  ## Nginx and php-fpm status
  include conf_m2/status.conf;

  ## Magento Setup Tool
  include conf_m2/setup.conf;

  ## Deny all internal locations
  location ~ ^/(app|generated|lib|bin|var|tmp|phpserver|vendor)/ {

    deny all;
  }

  location / {

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
  }

  ## Error log/page
  #  include conf_m2/error_page.conf;

  ## Static location
  include conf_m2/assets.conf;

  ## Protect extra directories
  include conf_m2/extra_protect.conf;

  ## Process php files (strict rule, define files to be executed)
  location ~ ^/(index|health_check|get|static|errors/(report|404|503))\.php$ {

    try_files $uri =404;
    #    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    include conf_m2/php_backend.conf;

    ## Enable Magento profiler
    #    fastcgi_param   MAGE_PROFILER html;

    ## Store code with multi domain
    fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE $MAGE_RUN_CODE;
    fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE $MAGE_RUN_TYPE;
    ## Enable POST logging in admin
    #    if ($request_method = POST) {set $adminpost A;}
    #    if ($request_uri ~* "/ADMIN_PLACEHOLDER/") {set $adminpost "${adminpost}B";}
    #    if ($adminpost = AB) { access_log /var/log/nginx/admin_post.log adminpost;}
  }

  ## Block other undefined php files, possible injections and random malware hooks.
  location ~* \.php$ {

    return 404;
  }
}
```

**PHP-FPM**

```
[www]
user = domain
group = domain
listen= 127.0.0.1:9000
access.format = "%{mega}MMb %{mili}dms pid=%p %C%% %R - %u %t \"%m %r%Q%q\" %s %f"
access.log = /var/log/php-fpm/$pool.access.log
listen.owner = nginx
listen.group = nginx
listen.mode = 0600
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1
pm = static
pm.max_children = 200
pm.start_servers = 5
pm.min_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_requests = 0
request_slowlog_timeout = 5s
slowlog = /var/log/php-fpm/$pool-slow.log
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php-fpm/$pool-error.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 2048M
php_admin_value[upload_max_filesize] = 11M
php_admin_value[post_max_size] = 12M
php_admin_value[max_input_vars] = 7000
php_admin_value[opcache.enable] = 1
php_admin_value[opcache.memory_consumption] = 256
php_admin_value[opcache.max_accelerated_files] = 65406
php_admin_value[opcache.blacklist_filename] = /home/domain.com/m2/public/.opcache-exclude.conf
php_admin_value[opcache.error_log] = /var/log/php-fpm/$pool-opcache-error.log

;php_value[session.save_handler] = files
;php_value[session.save_path]    = /var/lib/php/session
;php_value[soap.wsdl_cache_dir]  = /var/lib/php/wsdlcache
```

**MySQL**

```
# Percona Server template configuration

[mysqld]
#
# Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
# cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%.
# innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M
#
# Remove leading # to turn on a very important data integrity option: logging
# changes to the binary log between backups.
# log_bin
#
# Remove leading # to set options mainly useful for reporting servers.
# The server defaults are faster for transactions and fast SELECTs.
# Adjust sizes as needed, experiment to find the optimal values.
# join_buffer_size = 128M
# sort_buffer_size = 2M
# read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
skip-name-resolve
skip-secure-auth


# SAFETY #
max_allowed_packet             = 16M
max_connect_errors             = 1000000
innodb                         = FORCE

# BINARY LOGGING #
log_bin                        = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin
expire_logs_days               = 14
sync_binlog                    = 1

# CACHES AND LIMITS #
query_cache_type               = 0
query_cache_size               = 0
query_cache_limit              = 1M
tmp_table_size                 = 16M
max_heap_table_size            = 16M
join_buffer_size               = 256.0K
table_open_cache               = 2000
table_definition_cache         = 1400
key_buffer_size                = 271.5M

# Thread Pools #
thread_handling                = pool-of-threads
thread_pool_size               = 32
thread_pool_high_prio_mode     = none

# INNODB #
innodb_flush_method            = O_DIRECT
innodb_log_files_in_group      = 2
innodb_log_file_size           = 512M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_file_per_table          = 1
innodb_buffer_pool_size        = 23G
innodb_lock_wait_timeout       = 120
innodb_numa_interleave         = 1

# LOGGING #
general_log                    = 1
general_log_file               = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
log_error                      = /var/log/mysql/mysql_error.log
log_warnings                   = 2
log_queries_not_using_indexes  = 1
slow_query_log                 = 1
slow_query_log_file            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
```

**EDITED**

**MySQL Server SSD Information**

```
[root@db ~]# sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdb
smartctl 7.0 2018-12-30 r4883 [x86_64-linux-3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-18, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Samsung based SSDs
Device Model:     Samsung SSD 860 EVO 250GB
Serial Number:    S4BFNF0M906289Y
LU WWN Device Id: 5 002538 e49912e2f
Firmware Version: RVT03B6Q
User Capacity:    250,059,350,016 bytes [250 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-4 T13/BSR INCITS 529 revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.2, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Tue Mar 24 09:50:06 2020 PKT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                                        was never started.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x53) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        No Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (  85) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 1
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       3965
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       10
177 Wear_Leveling_Count     0x0013   045   045   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       994
179 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot   0x0013   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
182 Erase_Fail_Count_Total  0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0013   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
187 Uncorrectable_Error_Cnt 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0032   067   062   000    Old_age   Always       -       33
195 ECC_Error_Rate          0x001a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
199 CRC_Error_Count         0x003e   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
235 POR_Recovery_Count      0x0012   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       7
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       63100745018

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      3608         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
  256        0    65535  Read_scanning was never started
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

**MySQL Server CPU Information**: https://justpaste.it/2bnp9

**As for MySQL configuration, we are running Percona MySQL 5.7 and that is the only thing we got on the server** https://justpaste.it/3snvb

**SHOW GLOBAL STATUS**: https://justpaste.it/1lc9s

**SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES**: https://justpaste.it/2kfhn

**SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST**: https://justpaste.it/23a2m

**MySQL Tuner Report**: https://justpaste.it/5bwka

**ulimit -a**

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 127845
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 127845
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

**iostat -xm**

```
Linux 3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64      03/26/2020      _x86_64_        (24 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           5.57    0.00    0.33    0.58    0.00   93.52

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               2.83    34.59    4.77   75.50     0.49     2.02    64.07     0.14    1.73    2.14    1.70   1.43  11.51
sdb               2.81    34.59    4.17   75.49     0.46     2.02    63.60     0.17    2.10    2.27    2.09   1.62  12.93
md127             0.00     0.00    3.50   91.78     0.26     2.01    48.85     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
```

Comment: More information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I already edited my question with all the required information, let me know if you need any further informations.

Comment: Thank you, will analyze (maybe today).  What country/time zone are you in?  We are in UTC -6 Hrs Birmingham, AL USA (South of Chicago). View my profile, Network profile for contact info and consider free download of Utility Scripts to assist with performance tuning.  Our findfragtables.sql and find-redundant-indexes.sql can assist with conserving CPU cycles and storage space required.

Comment: UTC +0, as for the scripts I shall look into it today as well.

Comment: Optional very helpful information, if available includes - htop OR top for most active apps page 1 and page 2, please.  Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
innodb_flush_neighbors=2  # from 1 to reduce innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty quicker
innodb_buffer_pool_size=16G  # from 128M to support your 12.2 GB of innodb data in RAM
innodb_io_capacity=1900  # from 200 to use more of your SSD io capacity
read_rnd_buffer_size=192K  # from 256K to recude handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 12,291
read_buffer_size=256K  # from 128K to reduce handler_read_next RPS of 45,723
thread_cache_size=100  # from 9 to reduce threads_created
max_connections=300  # from 151 to support additional concurrent connections
connect_timeout=20  # from 10 to tolerate slow connects up to 20 seconds
```

You will find these configuration changes will REDUCE CPU significantly.

**This configuration may only increase CPU performance while using php-fpm instead of traditional apache+php**

Comment: Still, the DB pretty slow, also one more thing the moment we activated the thread-pool our application becomes super slow!

Comment: The turn it off, until you can determine WHY.  Most likely trying to drive too many concurrent processes. Posting htop results may help identify this situation.